# Proving $\int \int _Rf\left(\sqrt{\ \frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{y^2}{5}}\right)dA=2\pi \sqrt{\ 15}\int _0^1\ f\left(p\right)pdp$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Where where f is a continous function on $[0,1]$ and The region R is bounded by the ellipse $5x^2 + 3y^2 = 15$

I'm confused how to approach this, I just recently started with double integration and i have only completed the topic *Change of order of integration* and now i moved onto *Change of variable*.
So far i am familiar with question in change of variable where the transformation of the plane is given clearly for example $$T:ℝ^2\rightarrow \ ℝ^2,\ T\left(x,y\right)=\left(u+av,v\right)$$

In such cases like this transforming from xy-plane to uv-plane is fairly easy for me as the instructions are given clearly, but the question at hand is a bit confusing since its a little unclear to me. The only progress i made is draw the region R which is attached below:
[image]

Any help to walk me through the derivation is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure it's not $x^2/3+y^2/5$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured out how to solve this, I'm simply posting the answer in case someone else is also stuck in the same question:

First we can use polar coordinate system to solve this, our region R is enclosed in the ellipse given by $5x^2 +3y^2 =15$ rewriting it as $\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{y^2}{5}=1$, take the substitution as : $$x=r\sqrt{\ 3}\cos \theta, y= r\sqrt{\ 5}\sin \theta  $$ putting it into the ellipse equation we get: $r=1$ and taking the Jacabian we get
$J\left(r,\theta \right) = \left|\begin{array} {}
\frac {dx}{dr} & \frac {dx}{d\theta}\\
\frac {dy}{dr} & \frac {dy}{d\theta}\end{array}\right|=r\sqrt{\ 15}$

$\int _0^1\ \int _0^{2\pi}f\left(\sqrt{\ r^2}\ \right)r\sqrt{\ 15}d\theta dr$

$2\pi \sqrt{\ 15}\int _0^1\ f\left(\sqrt{\ r^2}\ \right)rd\theta dr$